# How to close msal browser pop up using JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure how to progamatically close the MSAL browser pop up in it's 2.0 version.
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js

Currently i trigger this popup through a click in a web page.

The window.close does not close the popup, is there an alternative way to achieve this ?

```
function msalAuth(){

const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'xxx',
    }
}

const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.ReadWrite"]
}

let accountId = "";

const myMsal = new msal.PublicClientApplication(config);

myMsal.loginPopup(loginRequest)
    .then(function (loginResponse) {
        accountId = loginResponse.account.homeAccountId;
        // Display signed-in user content, call API, etc.
    }).catch(function (error) {
        //login failure
        console.log(error);
    });

const callbackId = myMsal.addEventCallback((message) => {
     // This will be run every time an event is emitted after registering this callback
     if (message.eventType === msal.EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE) {
         const result = message.payload;  
         console.log("Failed auth !!")  
         // Some actions
         window.close(); // Want to close the popup window exactly here  


    }
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me a lot
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5006#issuecomment-1219426289

The `popupWindow` is a window object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

You can use popupWindow.close()
In my case I wanted to close the popup when I close a modal

```
  const closeModal = () => {
    setData({});
    if (popupWindow) {
      popupWindow.close();
    }
    toggle();
  }
```